# Equal Width Navbar Links with dropdown

Tags: css, nav

I would like to convert the Help link to a drop-down on hover. Do I have to convert this to an un-ordered list or can I use the existing structure. Thanks in advance.

```
 <div class="navbar-project">
   <a href="#">Details</a> 
   <a href="#">Forms</a> 
   <a href="#">Documents</a> 
   <a href="#">Help</a> 
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .navbar-project {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fff;
   overflow: auto;
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
 }

 .navbar-project a {
   float: left;
   padding: 12px;
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 3px solid white;
 }

 .navbar-project a:hover {
   border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 }

 .navbar-project a.active {
   background-color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 3px solid red;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .navbar-project a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to handle the dropdowns is to put them inside ul, you can adopt the below code in your existing code

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Button One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Button Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and your css

```
li {
 display: block;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need turn the Help item in a `ul`, create the `li` items and than use the `display: none;` to hide it, after that you can use `hover` in the `ul` and specify that you want the `li` items to appear using `display: block;`.

```css
.navbar-project {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fff;
   overflow: auto;
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
 }

 .navbar-project a {
   float: left;
   padding: 12px;
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 3px solid white;
 }

 .navbar-project a:hover {
   border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 }

 .navbar-project a.active {
   background-color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 3px solid red;
 }

.navbar-project ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.navbar-project ul li{
  display: none;
}

.navbar-project ul:hover li{
  display: block;
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .navbar-project a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }
```

```html
 <div class="navbar-project">
   <a href="#">Details</a> 
   <a href="#">Forms</a> 
   <a href="#">Documents</a> 
   <ul><a href="#">Help</a>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
     
   </ul> 
 </div>
```

> **Note:** I believe that for the sake of semantics it's good to always use `ul` or
>   `ol` in your `nav menu` as *Kai* explained in the other comment, so you just
>   need create another list inside the first one as I demonstraded.

**Edit:** I did some modifications and this time the width of 25% is working, [this is the example](https://codepen.io/mscarvalho/pen/ExjvdvY)

Comment: The Help link needs to maintain the 25% width to match the other nav links.  I will be adding a down carrot icon but want the help nav to match the existing format.